# How to prepopulate test database by necessary data?

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing, django-testing

I need to do some `unit tests` in my Django project. The problem is that almost every use case depends on prepopulated database objects.

For example, I want to create a product and test, if there were all `pre_save` signals successful.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Product


class ProductTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(username='test_user')
        self.product = Product.objects.create(name='Test product',user=self.user)


    def test_product_exists(self):
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.product)

    def product_is_active_by_default(self):
        ...
```

I can't do that because product has to have `User` object related. But I can't create a `User` object because `User` has to have related `plan` object. There are multiple plans in my production database from which one is default but there are no plans inside test database.

So to be able to do unit tests I need to prepopulate test database with multiple objects from multiple apps.

How can I do that?

Comment: I want to confirm @Gabriel Muj answer's as the best one in the long run (I can't post comments yet, so I put it as an answer). I've used hardcoded data for my tests, then used it with factories, which is a great improvement (factory boy), but, combining it with faker to create the data of the tested models is a huge plus.
Simplifies the process, the testing logic, testing writing time, and maintainability.
I just leave here the [article](https://hacksoft.io/improve-your-tests-django-fakes-and-factories/) that helped me with that combination.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can simply use django fixtures for that :-)

first populate a sample db with data then export data with [python manage.py dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/)

then in one of your apps create a directory named `fixtures` and put exported json file there (named `tests.json` or something else)

in your test class load fixtures like this

```
class ProductTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['tests.json', ]
```

checkout django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures)

PS: checkout factory boy too (@Gabriel Muj) answer

Answer (score 11):

I don't recommend using fixture since you will need to maintain them each time you make changes to the model. Here is a better approach on creating objects for tests by using this library https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which is more flexible.